# asp.net razor special character issue in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix

I'm using razor in webmatrix and I have a problem with the string special character. I want to put a string into a varibale in the javascript but when I try to use the tag @ it shows a problem 
this is the code :

```
<script>
 $Edit.click(function() {
        var userid = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
     var stringDiv = "@{ var selectQueryString4 =  SELECT * FROM DemandeConge where UserId = '\"+ trim(userid) + \"'\"+\";<h3>modifier la demande de congé de \" + userid +  \"</h3>foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString4)){<form action='responsable.cshtml' method=\"post\"><label for=\"txtDebut\">Date début :</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtDebut\" value=\"+ @row.DateDebutDemande +\"/></br><label for=\"txtFin\">Date de fin :</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtFin\" value=\"+ @row.DateFinDemande +\"/></br> <label for=\"txtTypeCong\">Type de congé :</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtTypeCong\" value=\"+ @row.TypeConge +\"/><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"UserId\" value=\"+ @row.UserId +\" /><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"type\" value=\"edite\" /><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Oui\"  /> <input type=\"button\" value=\"No\" onclick=\"$('#edite').slideUp(); document.getElementById('edite').innerHTML = ' '\" /> </form>}}}");


    document.getElementById('edite').innerHTML = stringDiv ;
        $('#edite').slideDown(1000);

        )
</script>
```

So I want to know if there is any way to solve this problem.

Comment: what is the problem shown ? what is the error that is returned ?

Comment: this is it : Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
http://imageup.fr/uploads/1330443764.jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use double @  like @@  instead of one @

Comment: this is it tnksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: U r Welcome , Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error , you must be using ' ' (simple quotes ) somewhere and it get compiled by the razor engine.
try to change all your ' in \" in your "" strings.

try for yourself , if you declare a string like this 'aa' you will get the same error in Csharp ,because you have to use "aa" to declare a string literal. '' are for character literals.

anyway in my opinion you should not mix js and C#. if you need to pass variables from C# to Js use either ajax ,or another solution like hidden input fields. or create templates like that :

```
<script type='text/template' id='mytemplate'>
<div>@myVar</div>
</script>
```

and get the content of the template with

```
$templateContent= $("#mytemplate").html()
```

Comment: tnkks dude ^^ but it does not work i steel have the problem with the @ tag